# How to disable bouncing effect while scrolling in figma?

Tags: user-interface, figma, mockups

My question is how to disable the bouncing effect while scrolling in Figma? I can't find any information about it in the documentation and I was thinking if is it possible to remove that effect at all. I mean scrolling in the emulator of figma.

Answer (score 1):

To date, there is no way to disable that effect.

**Workaround:**
To demonstrate scrolling without the bounce effect, you have to present part of your prototype as an animation, specific to that scrolling scenario. Then explain to the viewers that all scrolling behavior should follow that.